# convert ndarray values to numeric value for entire dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df like this:

```
a   b
1   2
3   4
```

but the datatype is each values is ndarray for example

```
type(df.a.values[0])
numpy.ndarray
```

and

```
df.a.values[0]
array([1])
```

I want to convert entire dataframe into numeric type and all value type should be int or float.

I tried this code

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

But this code is not working, how to deal with it ?

But when I am saving this file in local using to_csv and reading using read_csv, it's getting converted automatically. But how to convert on the fly ?

Comment: whta error you are getitng for df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)

Comment: I am not getting any error, but its not working, I mean the type is not changing

Comment: What is `print (df['a'].head().to_dict())` ?

Comment: @jezrael   {('a',): {0: 1}}

Comment: @KallolSamanta - Thanks, and `print(df.a.values.tolist())` ?

Comment: @jezrael  the value is  [[1]]

Comment: Hard is simulte your data, but you can test `df.a = np.array(df.a.values.tolist()).ravel()` ? and then `print (pd.to_numeric(df.a))` ?

Comment: @jezrael ravel() is not working and pd.to_numeric(df.a) gives me TypeError: arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series. 
and type(df.a) is pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

Comment: How did you create this DataFrame?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the type to numpy int or float by using

```
df.astype(np.float64)
```

after conversion you will get

```
dtype: float64
```

Comment: i tried to change one column as other columns are string. df.marks.astype(np.float) .   output: 0    30.0
1    56.0
2    66.0
3    33.0
4    34.0
5    56.0
6    32.0
Name: marks, dtype: float64

Comment: here the data type is ndarray, and the array is of float type already, and value is an array of single element, I want the values of float type not ndarray type

Comment: that too working for me.pd.to_numeric(df.marks) 0    30
1    56
2    66
3    33
4    34
5    56
6    32
Name: marks, dtype: int64. Dont think its python version dependent. Can you give me dataframe so that i can replicate the issue.

Comment: I guess your data frame value types are not np.ndarray

Answer (score 0):

If all of your cells contain only one value you can use

```
df.a.apply(lambda a: a[0])
```

to get the value out of the array contained in the cells.

It might be worth reworking the conversion from your data into the dataframe to get rid of these zero dimensional arrays, if possible.